# Cannot maintain internet connection on Linux Mint 18

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, wifi, dns

I am running Mint 18 (I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 - so I assume this is a general Ubuntu problem) where my internet connection goes out intermittently.

It stays connected to the wifi, but suddenly it cannot resolve any addresses. I have to turn wifi off and on again to reconnect (which is a pain since this is my media server)

I tried tailing the system log and saw something about resolver waking up- but wasn't sure if that was something to do with it or what it meant- couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure why this was put on hold, I felt it was pretty clear what I am asking. How to keep my connection from going out and not resolving dns issues.

Comment: Please post the system log regarding your issue...

Comment: Please add the following informations: `uname -a` , `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and  check your `cat /var/log/dmesg`

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case with realtek wifi i had to disable all power saving features of rtlwifi. 
If you also have a RealTek Wifi card, you can follow these steps:

```
lsmod |grep rtl #to identify the wifi module. In my case was rtl8192se. 
#alternatively search dmesg with grep wifi or grep rtl
modinfo rtl8192se  #to see available options for the module.
```

You should see something like this in the end:

```
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
```

If you have similar output, the parameter swlps , fwlps and ips are related to automatic power saving features.

You can unload the module and reload it with all power saving features disabled:

```
modprobe -r rtl8192se (that was the module in my case)
modprobe rtl8192 ips=0 fwlps=0 swlps=0
```

If everything is ok, you can make the changes permanent by going to `/etc/modprob.d` directory, open file `modesetting.conf` and add to the end:

```
options rtl8192se modeset=1
options rtl8192se fwlps=0 ips=0 swlps=0
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am not getting any output for grep rtl, lsmod |grep rtl, and I am not sure what the format should be with your last suggestion dmesg with grep wifi or grep rtl. 

Sorry, still fairly new to linux.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. We have the same card. I have done what you said. Just letting it go now and see if it resolves. Here's hoping. Thank you, I will let you know.

Comment: @AprilMarshall Well? How did it go? My card with above settings works for weeks without a single interrupt....

Comment: Still didn't work. Got a few hours out of it, then it went down again.

Comment: install sysfsutils (`apt-get install sysfsutils`) and then run `systool -a -v -m rtl8192se` to verify that power saving options are disabled indeed. All parameters should be advised with value "N" =disabled (fwlps,swlps, swenc and ips - debug will have value 0). If parameters are not advised as "N" but as "Y" then you have not disable them.

Comment: They are all at N or 0. 

However I ran the lsmod |grep rtl again and got this

rtl8192se              65536  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192se
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se
mac80211              737280  4 ath9k,rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se
cfg80211              565248  5 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211,rtlwifi


Did I get the right one changed, or do I need to do something with atheros?

Comment: @AprilMarshall So finally what is the status ? Is it fixed or still in trouble?

Comment: rebooted, and now systool says error opening the rtl8192se module and an lsmod |grep rtl returns nothing

Comment: run `modprobe rtl8291se`

Comment: "fatal: module rtl8291se not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic"

Comment: Strange. Did you uninstall any packages? Also have a look here https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=204172